# How to add a title to Seaborn Facet Plot

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, facet-grid

How do I add a title to this Seaborne plot? Let's give it a title 'I AM A TITLE'.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", row="smoker", margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Updating slightly, with seaborn 0.11.1:

Seaborn's `relplot` function creates a FacetGrid and gives each subplot its own explanatory title. You can add a title over the whole thing:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

rp = sns.relplot(data=tips, x='total_bill', y='tip',
                 col='sex', row='smoker',
                 kind='scatter')
# rp is a FacetGrid; 
# relplot is a nice organized way to use it

rp.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9) # adjust the Figure in rp
rp.fig.suptitle('ONE TITLE FOR ALL')
```

[image: Two-by-two grid of scatterplots. Each sub-plot has a title; the grid has a suptitle over all]

If you create the FacetGrid directly, as in the original example, it automatically adds column and row labels instead of individual subplot titles. We can still add a title to the whole thing:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import scatter as plt_scatter
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col='sex', row='smoker', 
                  margin_titles=True)
g.map(plt_scatter, 'total_bill', 'tip')
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
g.fig.suptitle('TITLE!')
```

[image: Two-by-two grid of scatterplots. Each column has a title and the overall grid has a supertitle.]

The FacetGrid objects are built with matplotlib Figure objects, so we can use `subplots_adjust`, `suptitle` that may be familiar from matplotlib in general.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to use `plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)` instead of `top=0.9`.

Comment: `suptitle` also has a `y` parameter. This worked for me: `g.fig.suptitle('foo', y=1.05)`

Comment: This does not work if you use `col_wrap` as then both the figure and the last axes subplot (bottom right) will inherit the same title.

Comment: instead of fiddling with the margins with `subplots_adjust()` simply calling `plt.tight_layout()` often times does the job quite nicely for you :)

Answer (score 48):

```
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
g.fig.suptitle('Title', fontsize=16)
```

More info here: http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html

Answer (score 22):

In ipython notebook, this worked for me!

```
sns.plt.title('YOUR TITLE HERE')
```

Comment: I tried this and it added a title to the bottom right figure, not the whole figure

Comment: Accessing `plt` via the `sns` package has been deprecated in 0.8.1. This should be done using `plt.title('YOUR TITLE HERE')`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'

Comment: AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'

Comment: @xApple & @seralouk: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

`sns.plt.suptitle('YOUR TITLE HERE')`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'

Comment: While this _can_ work if seaborn exposes it's matplotlib import, it's very bad practice to rely on another package to import your dependencies for you. You should just add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in your code and use `plt.suptitle` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The answers using `sns.plt.title()` and `sns.plt.suptitle()` don't work anymore.

Instead, you need to use matplotlib's `title()` function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.FacetGrid(<whatever>)
plt.title("A title")
```

Comment: This doesn't set the title in the correct location for me.

Comment: Did you try `plt.suptitle()`?

Comment: Your answer does not work as it affects the title of the last axes subplot (bottom right). Your suggestion `plt.suptitle()` also modifies the last axes as well as the main figure.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.suptitle("Title")
```

or

```
plt.title("Title")
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The second solution doesn't work, while the first solution creates an ugly interlay of suptitle and facet titles. You need to use using coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The title will not be center aligned with the subplot titles.
To set the position of the title you can use
`plt.suptitle("Title", x=center)`

In my case, my subplots were in a 2x1 grid, so I was able to use
`bbox = g.axes[0,0].get_position()` to find the bounding box and then `center=0.5*(bbox.x1+bbox.x2)`