# Add title to seaborn FacitGrid with only columns

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

This question is specific to adding a title to a facet grid plot where only columns are defined, it is not answered by [How to add a title to Seaborn Facet Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813694/how-to-add-a-title-to-seaborn-facet-plot).

I want to add a title to a FacetGrid where there is a single row of data, i.e. `row=None`.  When I do this the `subplots_adjust` call doesn't seem to be applied correctly and the title clashes with the column headings.

Here I show that the method in use works correctly for a FacetGrid with `col + row` data:

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", row="smoker", margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip")
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=.9)
g.fig.suptitle('col and row - needs to be long to show issue', size=14)
g.savefig('col_and_row.png')
```

[image: shows plot avoids title then both col and row defined]

The same but omitting the `row`:

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex", margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip")
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=.9)
g.fig.suptitle('col only - needs to be long to show issue', size=14)
g.savefig('col_only.png')
```

As you can see the title now clashes with the column headings:

[image: shows title clash when row omitted]

Is this a bug or have I missed something?

Comment: `g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=.8); g.fig.suptitle(..., y=0.95)` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750355/python-matplotlib-figure-title-overlaps-axes-label-when-using-twiny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct as per your code. You have given top=.9 and hence the subplots layout is adjusted according to '.9' value of 'top'. Try adjusting the 'top' value based on your requirments to get the desired output.

A slight modification to your code i.e. `g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=.8)` produced this output:

[image]

You can refer the parameters of subplots_adjust() at the following link: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html