# How can I add a title to a relplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, facet-grid

This should be easy, but I've tried many things (based on [seaborn relplot: how to control the location of the legend and add title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209895/seaborn-relplot-how-to-control-the-location-of-the-legend-and-add-title), [How to add a title to Seaborn Facet Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813694/how-to-add-a-title-to-seaborn-facet-plot) and also the documentation), but nothing worked.

Things I've tried:

```
g = sns.relplot(x="col1", y="col2", data=df, height=6, aspect=2);
g.add_legend(title="Col1 x Col2");
```

Also:

```
g = sns.relplot(x="col1", y="col2", data=df, height=6, aspect=2).set_title('Col1 x Col2')
```

And:

```
plt.title('Col1 x Col2')
g = sns.relplot(x="col1", y="col2", data=df, height=6, aspect=2);
```

Well, nothing worked. I want the title on the top of the graph, just like what plt.title() usually do.

Comment: is `g` a matplotlib Axes, matplotlib Figure, or a seaborn Grid?

Comment: The main answer to [How to add a title to Seaborn Facet Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813694/how-to-add-a-title-to-seaborn-facet-plot) has been updated for current Seaborn, and there's a complete `relplot` example in it now.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030162/7758804) in the duplicate, precedes this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you failed to include the source DataFrame, I used another one:

```
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

Then I created the *relplot* the following way:

```
g = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", data=df)
g.fig.suptitle('Col1 x Col2', fontsize=16)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9);
```

The result I got was:

[image]

Of course, the content of the image is different, but at least you have a title here, with the image adjusted down, to leave some space below the
title.